# Property does not exist on type - React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've found a lot of questions like this here on StackOverflow but I for the life of me cannot figure out what is wrong. I am quite new to React so that doesn't help at all.

What I am trying to do is, export a class from one file and import it in another and use it in that file.

Here is what the exporting file `storage.ts` looks like:

```
/*
 *   Class used to handle all storage requirements for this application
 */
export default class Storage {
    //Add an item to the local storage
    setLocalStorageItem(key: string, value: string) {
        window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
    }

    //Retrieves an item from local storage
    getLocalStorageItem(key: string) {
        //Create a varaible to retrieve the data
        const value = window.localStorage.getItem(key);

        //Check that value is populated
        if (value) {
            return JSON.parse(value);
        } else {
            return JSON.parse('');
        }
    }
}
```

And I am simply trying to import it as the following:

```
import * as themes from './theme/schema.json';
import Storage from './utilities/storage';

Storage.setLocalStorageItem("test", "test");
```

And I am running into this error in VS Code:

```
Property 'setLocalStorageItem' does not exist on type 'typeof Storage'.
```

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: You need either to create an instance of `Storage` or make the method `static`

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova - that makes perfect sense... Just like any other class in any other language...